# I need a simple website navigation in PHP

Tags: php, scripting, navigation

I'd like to write a new website from scratch. I'll be using PHP for server-side and Flash/HTML for client-side.

How can I achieve a website navigation something like this http://mariotestino.com/ [**site auto-plays sound**]

Notice when you click on Projects | Arts | Contacts...etc...you do not see .html page, instead it has a clean URL.

I'd rather not write the php script myself, since I don't know a single thing about syntax.
Is there a script that already does that?

Before you suggest WordPress, I've thought about that already but it's an overkill. I need something extremely fast and efficient without all the bloatware that WordPress ships with.
All I need is a simple website navigation and possibly a registration/contacts form. That's it. Everything else will be in HTML and Flash.

**Update: *Following Jason's link I have found a few frameworks that satisfy my needs and is exactly what I was looking for. One of them is [Symfony2](http://symfony-reloaded.org/) - it's really, fast, clean and gives me URLs in a nice SEO-friendly format!***

Comment: Before you down vote, please have some decency explaining why you're down voting.

Comment: +1 to counteract downvote for no reason

Comment: You sort of answered your own question....clean url's.

Comment: You're not exactly writing it from scratch if you're looking at someone else's code to figure out how to do it. Besides, something like that is usually handled by Apache (htaccess) first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a routing framework.  See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115629/simplest-php-routing-framework)